# How can I scrape a product price from a website using Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to extract the latest bid price for this sneaker from StockX but I'm getting the error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

since `sneaker_price` is coming up blank for some reason. Can anyone please help?:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://stockx.com/air-jordan-6-retro-travis-scott")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
driver.quit()

sneaker_price = soup.select("div.en-us stat-value stat-small")[0]
```

Comment: Please share the elements HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try CSS selector `div.en-us.stat-value.stat-small`:

```
sneaker_price = soup.select("div.en-us.stat-value.stat-small")[0]
print(sneaker_price.text)
```

Prints:

```
€523
```

---

Note: If you get captcha page, try to specify more HTTP headers and/or Cookies. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'
}

cookies = {
    'stockx_homepage': "sneakers",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://stockx.com/air-jordan-6-retro-travis-scott", headers=headers, cookies=cookies).content,"lxml")

sneaker_price = soup.select("div.en-us.stat-value.stat-small")[0]
print(sneaker_price.text)
```

Comment: I would make the change from [0] to [1] to ensure the latest value is captured. `sneaker_price = soup.select("div.en-us.stat-value.stat-small")[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.ask div.en-us.stat-value.stat-small` selector to get the div containing the latest ask price. And since there is more than one element you can select the last one such as:

```
ask_price = soup.select('.ask div.en-us.stat-value.stat-small')[-1]
print(ask_price.text) # $655
```